# Resize frame when text changes in figma auto layout frame

Tags: autolayout, figma

I'm trying to build a frame in Figma that resizes automatically when some text is changed, using auto layout.  When the text is added to the frame, it resizes according to the current string in the text.  However, the frame doesn't do anything when the text is edited later, either in the original component or any instance.  Is this just not possible?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you give me a link to a sample Figma file that contains the scenario you're describing? Indicate the frame that you want to resize automatically.